# Does mongo c# driver support server side projections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am a bit confused about projections with the driver.
I couldnt find some detailed specs in docs so would appreciate if someone could clarify.

Does mongodb .net driver support server side projections or are they always done client side after whole parent document(s) being transferred over the wire?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can choose what fields to project.

For example:

```
var field = new ExpressionFieldDefinition<MyDocModel, string>(x => x.Id);
await collection.DistinctAsync(myCollectionName, field, filter, options, timeout);
```